# Connecting to Oracle DB via python

Tags: python, oracle, jdbc

I'm using `jaydebeapi` to connect to an oracle DB. The code is as follows:

```
host = [address]
port = "1521"
sid = "ctginst1"
database = "oracle"
drivertype = "thin"
uid = [user]
pwd = [pass]

driver_class = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"

driver_file = "ojdbc10.jar"

connection_string="jdbc:{}:{}@{}:{}:{}".format(database, drivertype, host, port, sid)

conn=jaydebeapi.connect(driver_class, connection_string, [uid, pwd], driver_file, )
```

However this fails and gives me an error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver not found`

Edit:
By passing CLASSPATH with the .jar's location when starting JVM and only then attempting the connection I managed to proceed further with

```
import jpype
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), '-Djava.class.path=%s' % driver_file)
```

And now I am getting `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified` error

Comment: You need to pass the path to the JDBC driver as the last parameter to `connect`. See https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/#usage. The `CLASSPATH` environment variable isn't used for most ways of executing Java, and `JAVA_HOME\lib` definitely doesn't belong on it, and you shouldn't put random libraries that aren't part of Java itself in `JAVA_HOME\lib`.

Comment: I didn't copy the last line in full, the path to the driver is indeed present at the end.

Comment: Then `driver_file` should be the **full path** to the driver (or possibly a path relative to the Python program), not just the name of the driver jar.

Comment: The jar also exists at the root folder of the program. I've tried the full absolute path to it as well, like "C:\ojdbc10.jar".

Comment: `ojdbc10.jar` is for Java 10. Do you actually have Java 10 or higher installed? Does JayDeBeApi even work on Java 10?

Comment: Those are good points and I should use ojdbc8.jar instead. I checked and it says that jpype which jaydebeapi uses for java integration is compatible with java up to version 11. My java version is 8.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so from there there was apparently a colon missing before the "@".
The full successful connection code looks like:

```
import jaydebeapi
import jpype

host = host
port = "1521"
sid = "ctginst1"
database = "oracle"
drivertype = "thin"
uid = user
pwd = password

driver_class = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"

driver_file = "C:\ojdbc8.jar"

connection_string="jdbc:{}:{}:@{}:{}:{}".format(database, drivertype, host, port, sid)

jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), '-Djava.class.path=%s' % driver_file)

conn=jaydebeapi.connect(driver_class, connection_string, [uid, pwd])
```